# Can the corollary to the completeness axiom (the least upper bound property) be proved using the supremum of the set of lower bounds?

Tags: real-analysis

The corollary in question is, of course, the one regarding the existence of $\inf S$ for some nonempty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, that is bounded below.

I am already aware of the proof that involves taking the set $-S:=\{-s:s\in S\}$ and showing that $\inf S = -\sup (-S)$. I'm wondering if you could argue a different proof however; that if the set of the lower bounds of $S$ is $L$, then $\inf S = \sup L$, thus proving the corollary. I know that $\sup L$ exists because of the completeness axiom, however I don't have a clue how to show that $\sup L \in L$, or if you even can show it.

Would an argument such as this be sound? And if so, how would you go about showing that $\sup L \in L$?

I'm taking my first course in real analysis so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sup L\notin L$. Then $\sup L$ is not a lower bound for $S$. Which means $\exists s\in S$ such that $\sup L>s$. Then $s$ cannot be an upper bound for $L$. Which means $\exists l\in L$ such that $l>s$; contradicting the fact that $l$ is a lower bound for the set $S$. So you get $\sup L\in L$. This shows that the set of lower bounds has a maximum element, viz. $\sup L$. It is a lower bound for S, which is greater than all the other lower bounds. Then by definition, it is $\inf S$.